How to stop execution of SQLcl load when it hits an error (multiple tables loading)
I have multiple CSV files that need to be loaded into multiple Oracle tables.
I am using SQLcl (version 22.3) load functionality; I have a sql script (loadCSVs.sql) of the following format:
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK 
whenever oserror EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK 

set load errors 0
set load truncate on

load tableA input_tableA.csv 
load tableB input_tableB.csv 
load tableC input_tableC.csv 

Expected: if load into tableB fails for whatever reason (PK, FK, UK violations, not nullability etc etc) I need the execution to stop (so that I fix the CSVs and re-run).
Actual: execution continues, load into tableC goes on (so you end up with success for table A and C while load in B fails - having actually hundreds of tables/loading - it is easy to miss these errors).
I tried to capture the output of the execution (of the load statement and/or SQL file) - so the exit code - and depending on this exit or not but no success so far.
I considered also spool to a (log) file and read it for #ERROR - but don't like this approach.
How can I stop the execution of this (when tableB fails) ?
Any idea is welcome, thanks in advance!
Output:
SQL> @loadCSVs.sql

Load data into table tableA

csv
column_names on
delimiter ,
enclosures ""
encoding UTF8
row_limit off
row_terminator default
skip_rows 0
skip_after_names
batch_rows 50
batches_per_commit 10
clean_names transform
column_size rounded
commit on
date_format
errors 0
map_column_names off
method insert
timestamp_format yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF9
timestamptz_format
locale English United States
scan_rows 100
truncate on
unknown_columns_fail on

#INFO Number of rows processed: 2
#INFO Number of rows in error: 0
#INFO Last row processed in final committed batch: 2
SUCCESS: Processed without errors

Load data into table tableB

csv
column_names on
delimiter ,
enclosures ""
encoding UTF8
row_limit off
row_terminator default
skip_rows 0
skip_after_names
batch_rows 50
batches_per_commit 10
clean_names transform
column_size rounded
commit on
date_format
errors 0
map_column_names off
method insert
timestamp_format yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF9
timestamptz_format
locale English United States
scan_rows 100
truncate on
unknown_columns_fail on

#ERROR Insert failed in batch rows  1  through  2
#ERROR ORA-01722: invalid number
#ERROR Row 1 data follows:
< removed atual data for anonimization reasons>

#INFO Number of rows processed: 2
#INFO Number of rows in error: 2
#INFO No rows committed
ERROR: The Errors Allowed or the Error Limit parameter was exceeded

Load data into tableC

csv
column_names on
delimiter ,
enclosures ""
encoding UTF8
row_limit off
row_terminator default
skip_rows 0
skip_after_names
batch_rows 50
batches_per_commit 10
clean_names transform
column_size rounded
commit on
date_format
errors 0
map_column_names off
method insert
timestamp_format yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS.FF9
timestamptz_format
locale English United States
scan_rows 100
truncate on
unknown_columns_fail on

#INFO Number of rows processed: 28
#INFO Number of rows in error: 0
#INFO Last row processed in final committed batch: 28
SUCCESS: Processed without errors
SQL> version
Oracle SQLDeveloper Command-Line (SQLcl) version: 22.3.0.0 build: 22.3.0.257.1628
SQL>


Have you considered using SQL Loader for file loading? It's far superior than any scripting interface would be.

@PaulW, thanks for the input. Sometime in the past we had this discussion and I believe (I might be wrong though) we decided (in the org that the project is for) that SQLcl is the tool to be used because it also has Liquibase integrated in it (big dependency and needs to co-exist with this load functionality as well). I will re-visit this though (SQL Loader as an option, at least for the load). Thanks!

It's a bug. We'll have it fixed for an upcoming release of Oracle SQLcl.
